# Nested cursor performance tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, cursor

I have 2 cursors , one to fetch records from a table of 50 columns and 10,000 + data and another to check if a particular column exists in another big table (2 million data). I should write to a file all the records from cursor 1 for a year , if that column exists in cursor 2 then i should print an error message as exists and not delete them . If it does not exist then i should delete the row and write it to the same file and message as record deleted.
I used a nested cursor , the performance is too bad as it is processing each row from cursor 1 against cursor 2 , every time .

```
       CURSOR cursor1
         IS           
             select a.* ,a.rowid
              FROM table1 a 
              WHERE a.table1.year = p_year;
    
    CURSOR check_c2(lv_cd )
     IS
      Select DISTINCT 'Y' 
       from table2
       where table2 ='R'
       AND table2.year= p_year
       and table2_code= lv_cd ;

BEGIN :
   FOR r in cursor1 LOOP
            EXIT WHEN cursor1%NOTFOUND;
        
              OPEN check_c2(r.cd);
              FETCH check_c2 INTO lv_check;
                IF check_c2%NOTFOUND THEN
                    lv_check :='N';
                END IF;
                CLOSE check_c2;
       
                  IF lv_check ='Y' THEN
                   lv_msg =(r.col1,r.col2....r.col50, R code exists do not delete)
                   utl_file.put_line(lv_log_file, lv_msg, autoflush=>TRUE);
                   
                ELSE 
                  DELETE from table1 where rowid= r.rowid
                  lv_msg =(r.col1,r.col2....r.col50, delete row)
                   utl_file.put_line(lv_log_file, lv_msg, autoflush=>TRUE);
                   END IF;
                   END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have enough reputation to write comments som will write as an answer.

Didn't you try to add some time marks to understand which parts are the most time spending?

Does table2 have index by year and code? What's the explain plan of cursor2 query? If yes - how many rows are there average for year+code combination?
If the amount of data selected overall from table 2 is huge - then it probably can be faster to do a single query with full scan/index range scan by year on table2, grouping and hash left outer join from table1 to table2 like

```
select a.*, a.rowid, nvl2(c.code, 'Y', 'N') check_col
from table1 a,
(
    select distinct code
    from table2 b
    where b.year = p_year
) c
where a.year = p_year
  and c.code(+) = a.cd
```

Comment: @Doranaut I tried single query , the performance is much better than before . Thank you

Comment: @Doranaut - When i tried to add more conditions to table1 a , it keeps running forever . I just used and before the join to add the conditions

Comment: @arsha Additional conditions could change the execution plan.
The query text and it's execution plan are required at least to say anything.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? A 3-steps-operation:

Step 1: "save" rows you'll later delete

```
create table log_table as
select *
from table1 a
where exists (select null
              from table2 b
              where b.year = a.year
                and b.code = a.code
             );
```

Step 2: delete rows:

```
delete from table1 a
where exists (select null
              from table2 b
              where b.year = a.year
                and b.code = a.code
             );
```

Step 3: if you must, store rows saved in the LOG_TABLE into that file of yours. If not, leave them in `LOG_TABLE`.

Comment: So like storing it in a temp table . I am afraid i cannot do that .

Answer (score 0):

utl_file.put_line in the loop will be an overhead.Try appending to lv_msg till length  of the string is 32767 bytes and write just once.
This will definitely reduce the I/O and performance should be improved.

Comment: Should i append the utl_file.put_line instead of writing to it ?

Comment: You wouldn't want to cut lv_msg for a record in the middle. Keep appending to lv_msg with new line(chr(10)) and when the length is just less than 32767 write to file and reset lv_msg to null.

Comment: I tried this , performance was better only by few minutes . Thank you